# Why minify when the transport will gzip?

Tags: javascript, html

Back in the day (yes I really am this old) you could reference scripts out of a renamed zip file like this

```
<script archive="path/to.jar" src="some.js"></script>
```

This was supported on IE4, NS4 and Opera5 with identical mark-up and semantics, but has been consigned to the digital scrapyard. Why?

---

OK for those of you interested in the answer but not interested enough to trawl through an old message thread (see comments below) the long and the short of it is that you get the compression from the transport layer merely by specifying `Content-Encoding: gzip` so it is inappropriate to support mark-up in the presentation layer and therefore it was removed. This also improves granularity because script files are individually versioned in the cache.

Given the transport layer use of gzip, what is the point of minification? The gzip dictionary tokenising pass will achieve this over the wire without producing a horrible debugger experience.

I agree that concatenation will improve the compression yield. I suppose some server/browser combinations might fail to use gzip, in which case minification would help.

Comment: Discussed in [2003](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-html/2003Jan/0365.html). Step through the discussion by clicking "Next in thread". I would assume users are encouraged to concat, minify, and use modern compression when delivering external scripts. That effectively removes all purpose for `[archive]`.

Comment: Beat me to it... And what monster. jQuery caches well and is smaller than an average logo

Comment: So, does it work anymore, I was not aware of it.

Comment: I said jQueryUI not jQuery. jQueryUI.min.js is 224K

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### The `archive` Attribute

For anybody interested in what this attribute was, DevX made mention of it in their [Daily Tip on March 23, 1999](http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/5543). The original text is being duplicated here for preservation:

> ARCHIVE is a new attribute of the `<SCRIPT>` tag in Internet Explorer 4 and Netscape Navigator 4 that can speed up download times for sites with large JavaScript files. If you have several JavaScript files and digital signatures to load, it's more efficient to compress them into a single JAR (Java Archive) file. JAR archives are zipped files with self-descriptive information added. Within the JAR file, you still need to specify an external JavaScript file for each instance within an HTML page.
>
> `<SCRIPT ARCHIVE="myArchive.jar" SRC="myScript.js"></SCRIPT>`

#### Support in Modern Browsers

This is not in any standards track, nor do modern browsers appear to even support this attribute in a deprecated manner. A simple feature test indicates this:

```js
"archive" in document.createElement( "script" );
```

The results are pretty consistent:

- Chrome: False
- IExplorer: False
- Firefox: False
- Opera: False

#### Relevance Today

We don't really need a feature like this today in modern browsers. We now have [better encoding options](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip), and a plethora of [build](http://gruntjs.com/) [tools](http://gulpjs.com/) that concat and minify multiple dependencies. We also have utilities like [require.js](http://requirejs.org/) and [r.js](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js) that package up multiple files to reduce HTTP requests.

In short, the web blew right past the need for transferring zipped dependencies.

This same question was [asked in 2003 on the W3C's www-html mailing list](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-html/2003Jan/0365.html). A few of the arguments made for why an attribute like [archive] is no longer needed are listed below:

- Browsers are now capable of long-term caching to reduce future HTTP requests
- Browsers are now capable of far better content compression
- Browsers are now capable of persistent connections, reducing HTTP requests

#### Archived Publications

MSDN has a resourced titled [Script-based Security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms970704.aspx) that references this still today.

MDN also has an archived resource on the topic titled [Signed Scripts in Mozilla](http://www-archive.mozilla.org/projects/security/components/signed-scripts.html).

#### Response to Author

> Given the transport layer use of gzip, what is the point of minification? The gzip dictionary tokenising pass will achieve this over the wire without producing a horrible debugger experience.

It may be the case (not likely, but maybe) that the browser doesn't support gzip. In these instances, a concatenated/minified source would be far better. Modern build processes including minification steps also offer more granular control that gzip may not compete well against. For instance, minification can remove lengthy source comments.

As for the debugging experience, you can always leverage modern browser support for [source maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/source-maps) which should eliminate any need to actually debug minified code.

Comment: We still don't have ultra-fast and ultra-reliable connections across the globe though ;)

Comment: Have you noticed that Jonathon Sampson abbreviates to "JS"? Co-incidence? [cue X-files music]

Comment: @PeterWone Note my avatar ;) I am very proud of that coincidence, hehe.

Comment: It is no coincidence, Jonathan. JavaScript is your ***calling***

Comment: Well that solves another problem then. Now I have someone to blame for the fact that JS combined the prototype-based inheritance of Self, a quasi-functional aspect borrowed from LISP, a structured syntax adapted from C, and an aggressively asynchronous I/O model that requires elaborate callback chains. (Borrowed from this document: https://www.usenix.org/system/files/1403_02-08_mickens.pdf)

Comment: @PeterWone I came from a classical OO background, but grew to love the delegated model of prototype-based "inheritance". Having first-class functions is pretty nice too, in my sincere opinion ;) As far as the syntax goes, I love my curly-braces and semi-colons (even though both are largely optional). As for *elaborate callback chains*, delegates and promise objects have nearly wiped those out for me personally. Even great things are coming in the future too. I even saw an example of C#'s `await` being proposed for ES7.

Comment: JS, that was for humour value. Read the linked pdf and have a laugh. 
On a more serious note, you've done a wonderful job answering "why not archive" but (and yes I know BoltClock and I have moved the goalposts) you haven't yet addressed the question of "why minify given gzip?"

Comment: @PeterWone I actually just added that answer :)